# Cannot link external data with TopoJSON

Tags: topojson

I am trying to link a shapefile `europe.shp` with a `data.csv` external file while producing a TopoJSON file. They both have the `iso_a3` country code as common ID.

This is the head of `data.csv`:

```
iso_a3;anzahl_jets;typen1;typen2;typen3;text;pop
ALB;;;;;;3639453
AND;;;;;;83888
AUT;15;15 Eurofighter;;;;8210281
BEL;81;59 F-16;22 alte Saab;;;10414336
```

Converting `europe.shp` to `europe.json` alone works fine, all properties are preserved. 
When using the below statement though, only the properties of `europe.shp` are preserved (iso_a3 and name_de).

```
topojson --id-property iso_a3 -o europe.json -p iso_a3,jets=+anzahl_jets,pop=+pop,name_de=name_de --simplify-proportion 0.25 --width 900 --height 600 --external-properties data.csv -- countries=europe.shp
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`topojson` doesn't parse `;`-delimited CSV files. You need to use `,` or `\t` (the latter preferably with a file extension `.tsv`).

See https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/blob/master/bin/topojson#L369-L374